# Same value of min and max in min-max normalisation

Tags: normalization, computer-vision, data-preprocessing

By the definition of min-max normalisation, the value is divided by `max - min`, what if the `max` and `min` have the same value?

So I have read about [this anwser](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/205807/minmax-normalization-when-all-elements-are-same), but I am still not sure about my case.

For example, I have an image with n channels and I want to perform min-max normalisation over each channel i.e. $$x_{channel_a} = \frac{x_{channel_a} - min_{channel_a}}{max_{channel_a} - min_{channel_a}}$$

It is possible that only `channel a` is the same and other channels are different. Does it mean I should drop this channel information? How exactly can I do? What about setting the channel value to 0 if all channel values are the same?

If I drop this value, will it cause any loss of information. For example, I have a image with pixels value in RGB format `[12, 23, 34]`, `[12, 25, 87]`, `[12, 182, 230]`. Since R channel is the same, I can just drop it and the image become to `[0, 23, 34]`, `[0, 25, 87]`, `[0, 182, 230]`. Is this correct?

By the way, I am trying to use `ResNet-18` to extract the image features.

Comment: 0/0 is undefined

Comment: When you are willing to standardize your variables and max==min, you have no information.  Equivalently, you may replace the common value by any constant number you wish.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica That is the problem. I am trying to verify is that ok to set the value to any valid constant I want so that I can avoid dividedByZero error.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for clarifying that.

Comment: You could make a case for it being any number; 1/2 would be an obvious value to use in some situations, but any other value could be just as meaningful / equally meaningless in another situation. I'd be inclined to just use "missing" (however that's handled in whatever you're using) for those values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\min_i x_i = \max_i x_i$ then this implies that $x_1 = \cdots = x_n$ (i.e., all data values are the same).  In that case, there is not really any difference to "normalise".  By convention, you would probability set the "normalised" values to $z_1 = \cdots = z_n = 0$ in this case, which shifts them to a mean of zero, and retains the property that:

$$z_k (\max_i x_i - \min_i x_i) = x_k - \min_i x_i.$$